# Movie about kilted soldiers lifting their kilts in a war with Indian soldiers?

Tags: identify-this-movie

I remember watching an English comedy movie on TV in around 1996, where there is a kilted regiment planning an attack against an Indian kingdom. The Indian king is worried about the kilted soldiers not wearing any underpants, but a spy tells the king that they do wear underpants.
The most hilarious scene is when the Indians and the kilted soldiers are facing each other for war, the Indians charge for battle and the kilted soldiers calmly lift their kilts and expose their...err...front side. The Indian soldiers see that, start screaming in horror and run away.

One other scene I remember is when the foreigners are hosted by the Indian king and some women are sent to entertain them. The foreigners are mesmerized by the amount of jewelry the women wear. Each time they comment about the woman's necklace or bangles, the woman removes the necklace and bangle and gives it to the foreigner as a gift, because he is their guest. Then he comments about her jewel studded bra, she proceeds to start removing it, he says "No, no, no, no", stops her, and uses a sharp tool to slowly yank the jewels from the bra.

Please don't misunderstand this question. This is an actual movie I watched a long time ago (and is not porn), but am unable to find it with a Google search. Would be grateful if you could help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### *[Carry On... Up the Khyber](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0062782/)*

Here you can watch the complete movie:

http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1sq604_carry-on-up-the-khyber-1968-full-movie_shortfilms

Ca. the 0:41 mark starts the scene with the women and the jewelry, bra, etc.

Right at the end, ca. the 1:24:30 mark you can see the soldiers lining up and lifting up their kilts.

From Wikipedia:

> "The province is defended by the feared 3rd Foot and Mouth Regiment (The Devils in Skirts), who are said **to not wear anything under their kilts.** When Private Widdle (Charles Hawtrey) is found wearing underpants after an encounter with the warlord Bungdit Din (Bernard Bresslaw), chief of the warlike Burpa tribe, the Khasi of Khalabar (Kenneth Williams) plans to use this information to incite an anti-British rebellion. He aims to dispel the "tough" image of the Devils in Skirts by revealing that contrary to popular belief, they do indeed wear underpants under their kilts."
>
> "Still dressed in black tie, **Sir Sidney orders the Regiment to form a line and lift their kilts, this time exposing their (implied) lack of underwear. The invading army is terrified, and retreats at once.**"

Comment: Bingo! Thank you. Also found it on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TaJqaDnhS0

Comment: Yes, spot on. However, the movie was filmed on location in North Wales!